# Stripe customer integration on bootstrap html site

Tags: javascript, html, curl, stripe-payments

I built an ecommerce website using twitter bootstrap that I wish to take subscription payments from using Stripe. I want to create a new customer that has a subscription using the example code seen [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/curl#customers) on the stripe site. It has the option to execute this code using various languages (curl,ruby,python,pho,java). How can I implement this on my very basic bootstrap based website that has no real backend?

Comment: No way around it without some third party service. Setting up a server is your only other option. It's dead simple to do... they couldn't have made it any easier.

Comment: Do you know ruby / php by chance? That's the only two languages I've used it with. php would be easiest since practically everyone supports it.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a real backend one way or another. You could use Heroku, or build a simple backend on your server. I really like the nginx/gunicorn/supervisor/flask stack. I've used [this tutorial](http://www.onurguzel.com/how-to-run-flask-applications-with-nginx-using-gunicorn/) several times, and it is very nice (you need to follow the link at the bottom and configure supervisor to finish it).

Also, check out the [flaskr tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/tutorial/introduction/) to get your bootstrap site all plugged in and ready on top of the stack so you can get started with the stripe python integration.

Good luck-- you've got a lot of work to do : )

Comment: I'm not totally sure-- I imagine it depends on your prior experience more than anything. I wouldn't build a checkout page from scratch if I were you though. No reason to reinvent the wheel.